# Как правильно реализовать функцию в конструкторе класса javascript?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Здравствуйте,
столкнулся с проблемой реализации самовызывающейся функции в конструкторе класса.
Создал класс с помощью конструктора, добавил к нему логики, однако вылетает ошибка, что я не могу применить метод push к массиву. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function PaginationHelper (collection, itemsPerPage) {
    this.collection = collection;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.paginationPages = [];
    this.paginate = (function() {
    var tempArray = [];
        tempArray = tempArray.concat(this.collection)
        sliced = tempArray.length - this.itemsPerPage,
        count = tempArray.length;

    while(count>0){
        var page = tempArray.splice(sliced);
        this.paginationPages.push(page);
        count -= this.itemsPerPage;
        sliced -= this.itemsPerPage;
    }
    return this.paginationPages;
})();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю это ли Вам нужно, но наверное так.

```
function PaginationHelper (collection, itemsPerPage) {
    this.collection = collection;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.paginationPages = [];
    this.paginate = (function(th) {
        var tempArray = [];
        tempArray = tempArray.concat(th.collection);
        var sliced = tempArray.length - th.itemsPerPage;
        var count = tempArray.length;

        while(count>0){
            var page = tempArray.splice(sliced);
            th.paginationPages.push(page);
            count -= th.itemsPerPage;
            sliced -= th.itemsPerPage;
        }
        return th.paginationPages;
    })(this);
}
```